# How can I reset a MYSQL table through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, reset

It may seem like a simple question with an easy answer.

I would merely like to create a way to from a PHP page, clear a table while still leaving the empty columns the deletion would create.

I have tried to look this up, but everything seems extremely overcomplicated. I don't want to use Java or any other language. Only PHP.

Answer (score 3):

If by reset you mean removing all the data from your table than you can use Truncate table_name:

```
mysql_query("TRUNCATE table_name");
```

Comment: It is `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name`, is it not? Also, why `mysql_query`?

Comment: Yes you can add the word table but it is optional [MySql Truncate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html)

Comment: Didn't know [TABLE] was optional. Rolled Back